# Not Able to See the Picture in Tkinter Python Program

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```py
topper = Toplevel()
topper.title("2nd Window")
topper.state('zoomed')
my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("diamond.png"))
my_label = Label(topper, image=my_img, height = 100 , width = 100)
F21 = Frame(topper, borderwidth=83, bg="blue", relief=SUNKEN)
button1 = Button(topper, text="class", command=topper.destroy)
button1.pack()
my_label.pack()
```

I am running the code and I get no errors, button is working as well but I'm not able to see the picture in the window.

Comment: Is the code inside a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow Shakti!

For the future - it is always good to supply a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can replicate and understand your issue better in order to help you! It also helps you to understand where exactly the error originates.

When you call Toplevel() from another tkinter window to open a new window, you will need to call "mainloop()" on the second window as well in order to display an image - try my code with an example image and comment/uncomment the line with

```
topper.mainloop()
```

to see the difference in functionality.

The adapted code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk   # pip install pillow

def show_second_window():
    topper = Toplevel()
    topper.title("2nd Window")
    topper.state('zoomed')
    my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("t1.png"))
    my_label = Label(topper, image=my_img, height=100, width=100)
    F21 = Frame(topper, borderwidth=83, bg="blue", relief=SUNKEN)
    button1 = Button(topper, text="class", command=topper.destroy)
    button1.pack()
    my_label.pack()

    topper.mainloop()  # <---- this is needed to show the image!


root = Tk()
root.title("1st window")
button = Button(root, text="show second window", command=show_second_window)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The `Toplevel` function is a tkinter widget.

Comment: thanks Bryan! I adapted the code but it still runs in my case, so I'm guessing either the error lies with the "diamond.png" or outside the code Shakti has given.

Comment: Sir It is working on this file and picture is being shown but when I connected this window with another window than on click of that window this window is opening but the image is not being shown.

Comment: ahhh, okay, now I understood your problem! I will edit my code in a second

Comment: If the answer helped you solving your problem, please vote on it and accept it :) -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers